# Flask-soketio works partially upon deployment

Tags: html, css, vue.js, flask-socketio

I have created simple chat based on Flask-Socketio, Vue.js and html/css. Application works fine locally, with socketio.run. But upon deployment the application work showing only rendering of html input and button. Background, chat window messages are missing.
Could you please help to understand the reason of the application displayed partially upon deployment?

Here is the server-side code:

```
import os
from os import environ
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, send
from flask import session

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
app = Flask(__name__)
#Creating path to the file with secret key
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = environ.get('KEY')
socketio = SocketIO(app, manage_session = False)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('session.html')


@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(msg):
    send(msg, broadcast = True)

@socketio.on('join')
def join_username(username):
    emit('message', {'user':'Chat', 'message':username  + ' joined this chatroom'}, broadcast = True)
    socketio.sleep(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug = True)



And heroky.yml:

build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
run:
  web: gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 chat:app
```

Comment: According to the log, application got:
" RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: Solved. The problem caused by two main issues:
1) Gunicorn version 20.0 should be downgraded to 19.0

2) Hosting address should have been stated in cors_allowed_origins='https://address.com'  of SocketIO() constructor.